# Converting String to Money

Tags: java, java-8, joda-money

I am having the below String

```
String money = "USD0.00"
```

Want to convert this into `org.joda.money.Money`

Do I need to split the currency unit and double value here and need to set it as separately in Money. Or Any library api is there to convert this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Money.parse()`.

From the [documentation](https://www.joda.org/joda-money/apidocs/org.joda.money/org/joda/money/Money.html#parse(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine)

> The string format is '$currencyCode $amount' *where there may be zero to many spaces between the two parts*.